# Visual Studio 2013 - Press enter to select text from the list

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio-2013, selection

Normally i can simply press enter to select the text from the list (or whatever it called) while typing the methods. After i installed Productivity Power Tools 2013 add-in, it ruined VS2013 programming workspace so i have to unistall the add-in. After that, i notice that auto select a text from the list does not work anymore. When i press ENTER, it just create a new line instead select the text it already selected. I have to manually press UP or DOWN to select or use the mouse to select text from the list.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your setting of Edit -> IntelliSense -> Toggle Completion Mode. This setting is often toggled by accident because its default shortcut is Ctrl+Space or something like that (not sure right now, I've removed that shortcut).

Comment: I had the same issue but I checked the "Toggle Completion Mode" and it wasn't on. I also tried to change the shortcut but it won't let me put "enter" instead of Ctrl-Space. How did you remove it ? (I might also add, that I'm using Visual Studio 2017).

Comment: @NewBie1234 I simply removed it in the options. Tools - Options - Environment - Keyboard - search for "togglecompletion" - click remove

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing `Spacebar` instead of `Enter` to go with the default intellisense value.  Either one works for me, though.  `Tab` also works.